# Laravel 4: left join with where claus not showing none linked rows

Tags: laravel-4, left-join

I am trying to build a Artisan Cron Job in the Laravel 4 that gets all our subscribers that should pay using the Eloquent ORM. I am trying to accomplish that I get all users with a subscription who paid for the last time at least one month ago, or new subscriptions who never paid at all.
Yet I only get the info from the user table (user 1 and 3), the values of the payment table are 'null'. Which means they are not with in range, however I only want 'null' values if they don't have any values in table payments.

my code:

```
$Payments = user::leftJoin('payments', function ($query) {
     $query->on ('payments.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
        ->where ('payments.paid_on', '<=', 
            date('Y-m-d H:i:s',mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-1, date("d"),   date("Y"))))
        ->where ('payments.paid_on', '>=', 
            date('Y-m-d H:i:s',mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-1, date("d")-10, date("Y"))));
   })
  ->where('user.start', '<', date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time()) )
  ->where('user.end', '>', date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time()) )
   ->get(['user.*','payments.paid_on']);
```

This is example data:

```
(user)
 id    start                 end
| 1 | 2014-02-24 00:00:00 | 2015-02-24 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2012-03-24 00:00:00 | 2013-01-24 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 2014-03-24 00:00:00 | 2015-03-24 00:00:00 |

(payments)
user_id   paid_on
| 1    | 2014-02-24 00:00:00 |
| 1    | 2014-03-24 00:00:00 |
| 2    | 2013-01-24 00:00:00 |
```

I hope it would out put something like:

```
| 1 | 2014-02-24 00:00:00 | 2015-02-24 00:00:00 | 1    | 2014-03-24 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 2014-03-24 00:00:00 | 2015-03-24 00:00:00 |
```

Comment: The output you hope for doesn't satisfy the condition `where ('payments.paid_on', '>=', date(...)`, does it?

Comment: Well no since the "paid_on" is empty, I found questions that solve this in plain SQL, but I hope to solve it throught the Query Builder and the translation part is lost on me:$

Comment: The problem with that query is definitely in the get() - this way you select user.id and payments.id, both columns name 'id' thus Eloquent doesn't know which id it should assign. Use get(['user.*', 'payments.field1',...]) instead, omitting the payments.id or aliasing it. Apart from that it's OK, and probably there is no data to return

Comment: @deczo Thx for your response. Yet that doesn't seem to work. As I understand it (and have seen in practice)  a doable column name will just be overwritten, it does not cause any problems (accept if you are looking for a value in those columns;-))

Comment: You get me wrong. As I said the query is ok and probably there is no data to retrieve. id issue is not causing it. Looking at your code I suppose you have a mistake in your first `where` - it checks for users who have start field in future but paid in past 30 days, isn't it

Comment: @deczo So I see my error thank you so much. It is a artisan cron job that should check for uses who have an active subscription and have last paid over a month ago (since we want the get subscription fees once a month). My code will output all the payments ever made for active users, it should be limited till a couple of days earlier I guess... thx again!

Answer (score 0):

don't know if I came to the right conclusion but this is what I ended up with. Check if a value existed in the right table in the where clause and if it didn't I checked if there was one for NULL. Here is the code:

```
$Payments = user::leftJoin('payments', 'user.id', '=', 'payments.user_id')
  ->where('user.start', '<', date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time()) )
  ->where('user.end', '>', date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time()) )
  ->where (function($query)
  {
     $query->where ('payments.paid_on', '<=', 
        date('Y-m-d H:i:s',mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-1, date("d"),   date("Y"))))
      ->where ('payments.paid_on', '>=', 
        date('Y-m-d H:i:s',mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-1, date("d")-5, date("Y"))))
      ->orWhere(function($orQuery)
      {
         $orQuery->whereNull ('payments.paid');
      });

  }
  ->get(['user.*','payments.paid_on']);
```